# Using expect multiple times in /usr/bin/expect

Tags: bash, automation, expect, disque

I'm trying to automate some calls from a message oriented middleware application called disque using disque and I'm running into some difficulty...

Everytime I want the client to run a command, I must expect the prompt it gives and send the command, but when I try to do it more than once, I run into problems.

Here is the expect script in its most basic non-functioning form:

```
set timeout 20


spawn "./disque"

set timeout 10
expect  "127.0.0.1:7711> "  {send "ADDJOB scriptqueue body 0\r"}
set timeout 10
expect  "127.0.0.1:7711> "  {send "GETJOB FROM scriptqueue\r"}
```

However, when I run the above script, only the first prompt is read and the first message is sent.  The GETJOB command never is run.

Here is the output I get:

```
spawn ./disque
127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body 0
```

Also as a reference, this is how disque works normally when I manually input those two strings when I'm prompted:

```
127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body 0
DI530404a85743c0afe1353ae1943df8d86c9f561005a0SQ
127.0.0.1:7711> GETJOB FROM scriptqueue
1) 1) "scriptqueue"
   2) "DI530404a806ff88886c366ba3566d7e36ea81f89605a0SQ"
   3) "body"
127.0.0.1:7711>
```

UPDATE:

I just ran the script using the -d for debug mode and got this output:

```
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = cng4.sh
set argc 0
set argv0 "cng4.sh"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file cng4.sh
spawn ./disque
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {17657}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*>"? no
127.0.0.1:7711>
expect: does "127.0.0.1:7711> " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*>"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "127.0.0.1:7711>"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "127.0.0.1:7711>"
send: sending "ADDJOB scriptqueue body 0\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*>"? no
127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body 0
DI530404a8efd0d77b5bb62a7568510f7b6a29a13405a0SQ
127.0.0.1:7711>
expect: does " \r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> A\r\u001b[17C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> AD\r\u001b[18C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADD\r\u001b[19C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJ\r\u001b[20C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJO\r\u001b[21C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB\r\u001b[22C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB \r\u001b[23C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB s\r\u001b[24C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB sc\r\u001b[25C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scr\r\u001b[26C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scri\r\u001b[27C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scrip\r\u001b[28C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB script\r\u001b[29C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptq\r\u001b[30C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqu\r\u001b[31C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptque\r\u001b[32C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueu\r\u001b[33C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue\r\u001b[34C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue \r\u001b[35C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue b\r\u001b[36C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue bo\r\u001b[37C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue bod\r\u001b[38C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body\r\u001b[39C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body \r\u001b[40C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body 0\r\u001b[41C\r\nDI530404a8efd0d77b5bb62a7568510f7b6a29a13405a0SQ\r\n127.0.0.1:7711> " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "*>"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) " \r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> A\r\u001b[17C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> AD\r\u001b[18C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADD\r\u001b[19C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJ\r\u001b[20C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJO\r\u001b[21C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB\r\u001b[22C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB \r\u001b[23C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB s\r\u001b[24C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB sc\r\u001b[25C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scr\r\u001b[26C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scri\r\u001b[27C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scrip\r\u001b[28C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB script\r\u001b[29C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptq\r\u001b[30C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqu\r\u001b[31C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptque\r\u001b[32C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueu\r\u001b[33C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue\r\u001b[34C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue \r\u001b[35C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue b\r\u001b[36C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue bo\r\u001b[37C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue bod\r\u001b[38C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body\r\u001b[39C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body \r\u001b[40C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body 0\r\u001b[41C\r\nDI530404a8efd0d77b5bb62a7568510f7b6a29a13405a0SQ\r\n127.0.0.1:7711>"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> A\r\u001b[17C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> AD\r\u001b[18C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADD\r\u001b[19C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJ\r\u001b[20C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJO\r\u001b[21C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB\r\u001b[22C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB \r\u001b[23C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB s\r\u001b[24C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB sc\r\u001b[25C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scr\r\u001b[26C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scri\r\u001b[27C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scrip\r\u001b[28C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB script\r\u001b[29C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptq\r\u001b[30C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqu\r\u001b[31C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptque\r\u001b[32C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueu\r\u001b[33C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue\r\u001b[34C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue \r\u001b[35C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue b\r\u001b[36C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue bo\r\u001b[37C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue bod\r\u001b[38C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body\r\u001b[39C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body \r\u001b[40C\r\u001b[0K127.0.0.1:7711> ADDJOB scriptqueue body 0\r\u001b[41C\r\nDI530404a8efd0d77b5bb62a7568510f7b6a29a13405a0SQ\r\n127.0.0.1:7711>"
send: sending "GETJOB FROM scriptqueue\r" to { exp4 }
```

It looks like the reason is that it's picking up some other output from the disque application itself...I'm still not sure how to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the debug log, `GETJOB` was really sent to the application. The problem is you did not wait for `GETJOB` to finish. Just think how do you know the `GETJOB` has finished when you manually interact with the application? You wait for the next prompt, right? So just tell `expect` to do the same thing. That's to say, tell `expect` to wait for the next prompt before it moves on (or exit).

```
expect "127.0.0.1:7711> " {send "GETJOB FROM scriptqueue\r"}
expect "127.0.0.1:7711> "
```

Comment: That didn't do anything.  I got the same output, and a similar debug view:

Comment: Could you post the new debug output?